# Java HTTP connection.getInputStream() get response from exception

Tags: java, web-services, exception

Hello all in my doe I have a try catch and I am catching the exception from a webservice

However If I run my web service in Firefox Poster add-on I get a response as well as a stastus exception

This obviously is not ALL the code but basically the exception is happening at `getInputStream()`

How can I get the response from the exception?

```
try{
//Get Response
stream = connection.getInputStream();

} catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException("Exception - " + e.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
String msg = connection.getResponseMessage();
```

These methods will still throw `IOException` if you can't reach the server. But if the server responds, even with an error, these methods give you access to the response.

Comment: I get `Unprocessable Entity Exception`

Comment: That sounds like an error message from the server. In other words, this part of your code is working, but you aren't sending the right data to the web service.

Comment: I get that...the problem is..If I send the same data through a poster add-on through firefox I get an xml response with an actual error messae I can use in the form of a response object...java is throwing an exception before I can even read a response.....I cant seem to tap into to that

Comment: Have you read the data from `connection.getErrorStream()`? That will return the body of an error result.

Comment: Hey thanks!!.That did it...got the error number and error messgae!!